# On a Corollary to Gauss' Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Suppose $R$ is a UFD, with $F$ its field of fractions.

A usual corollary to Gauss' Lemma on the content of polynomials states that if $f(X)\in F[X]$ has a factorization $f(X)=g(X)h(X)$ in $F[X]$, then if $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are primitive and in $R[X]$, then so is $h(X)$. Why is $h(X)$ necessarily in $R[X]$?

Comment: $F$ is a field, so isn't every (non-zero) polynomial $f\in F[x]$ primitive as an element of $F[x]$, because every element of $F$ is invertible? (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)#Formal_statements)) And if that's not what you mean... then what do you mean?

Comment: You're right, my question didn't make sense. I've tried to pinpoint what I'm really asking for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every prime $p$ we have $0=v_p(f)=v_p(g)+v_p(h)=v_p(h)$, thus $h$ is primitive and in $R[X]$. Here, $v_p$ denotes the largest $n$ such that $p^n$ divides all the coefficients.